# Conversion failed error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to run the below query

```
DECLARE @A VARCHAR(256) = '3.5'

SELECT 
    CASE @A WHEN 'N/A' THEN -1 ELSE @A 
END
```

but I get this error:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '3.5' to data type int.

I can't figure out why!

Comment: the problem is that `-1` is `int` and `@A` is `varchar`. make the -1 as varchar. see my answere :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `CASE` expression returns two different types of data:

```
CASE @A 
   WHEN 'N/A' THEN -1      -- returns an INT
   ELSE @A                 -- returns VARCHAR(256)
END
```

SQL Server will now try to **normalize** this response and tries to convert both responses to the data type with the higher precedence (see: [Data Type Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx) on MSDN for details) - in this case, `INT`. So SQL Server tries to convert `@A` to an `INT` and obviously fails.

`CASE` is an **expression** in T-SQL - it returns exactly **one atomic value**, and **all** different "paths" in a `CASE` expression should return the **same datatype** - otherwise you run into problems like this ....

Answer (score 2):

the problem is that -1 is int and @A is varchar

this should work for you: make the -1 as varchar too

```
DECLARE @A varchar(256) = '3.5'

SELECT 
    CASE @A WHEN 'N/A' THEN '-1' ELSE @A 
END
```

Comment: The clock shows that this answer was posted 1 minute later than marc_s's, and it is essentially the same answer.

Comment: @DanBracuk yes but my comment was posted first :) no idea why no upvote, since it's right

Answer (score 1):

```
Try this

DECLARE @A VARCHAR(200) = '4.5'

SELECT CASE @A WHEN 'N/A' THEN CAST(-1 AS VARCHAR) ELSE @A END
```